# View is sending a null list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I'm having a problem with a null list of objects when I try send from view to controller,
the `jobOffertModel` parameter is null

Here is my controller method: (I know it doesn't nothing, but I was testing the parameters)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AcceptJobOfferts(IEnumerable<JobOffertModel> jobOffertModel)
{
    initBusinessObjects();

    return View();
}
```

And Here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TCCApplication.Models.JobOffertModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Minhas ofertas de trabalho";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptJobOfferts","Professional")){

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Oferta: </label>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Description)
                </div>

                @if (item.Acepted)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Aceitar?</label>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Acepted)
                    </div>
                }
                else
                { 
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Aceitar?</label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(itemModel => item.Acepted)
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Ativa</label>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Active)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Data do trabalho</label>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.JobDate)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" value="Aceitar ofertas de trabalho"/>
    </div>

</div>

}
```

The user goes to view using this method:

```
public ActionResult ViewMyJobOfferts(int professionalId)
{
    initBusinessObjects();

    var professionalJobOfferts = jobOffertBusiness.GetJobOffertsByProfessional(professionalId);

    return View(professionalJobOfferts);
}
```

Comment: Is that your complete code? where are you closing the using statement? @using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptJobOfferts","Professional")){

Comment: I'm closing the form, It was a problem in my post text

Comment: I believe you have to use an IList instead of IEnumerable and iterate with a for loop instead of a foreach, else the binding won't work.

Comment: @failedprogramming It really works, I'm binding the list now, but my objects are "empty" when I post the form, could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes what I have done -

1. Convert IEnumerable to List() with variable called modelList.
2. Used For Loop to display all property values.
3. Used hidden fields to persist only display element properties for POST operation.
4. Changed parameter name of POST Controller Action to modelList.

You got to have your view something like this -

```
@model IEnumerable<TCCApplication.Models.JobOffertModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Minhas ofertas de trabalho";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptJobOfferts","Professional", FormMethod.Post)){
var modelList = Model.ToList();
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        for (int i = 0; i < modelList.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Oferta: </label>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => modelList[i].Description)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(itemModel => modelList[i].Description)
                </div>

                @if (modelList[i].Acepted)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Aceitar?</label>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel =>  modelList[i].Acepted)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(itemModel =>  modelList[i].Acepted)
                    </div>
                }
                else
                { 
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Aceitar?</label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(itemModel =>  modelList[i].Acepted)
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Ativa</label>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => modelList[i].Active)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(itemModel => modelList[i].Active)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Data do trabalho</label>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel =>  modelList[i].JobDate)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(itemModel =>  modelList[i].JobDate)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" value="Aceitar ofertas de trabalho"/>
    </div>

</div>

}
```

And then your controller should be -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AcceptJobOfferts(IEnumerable<JobOffertModel> modelList)
{
    initBusinessObjects();

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptJobOfferts","Professional")){
```

By:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptJobOfferts","Professional", FormMethod.Post)){
```